# No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, owin

I am trying to use OWIN Security for my ASP.net VB Form website.  I am basing my code off of this MVC c# example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation

I added a startup.cs class to my root directory, which has this code:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(mysite.Startup))]
```

namespace mysite
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
In my web.config file, I have added this:

```
</appSettings>
   <add key="owin:AppStartup" value ="startup.cs"/>    
   .... other settings here
</appSettings>
```

And, finally, in my App_Start folder, I added Startup.Auth.vb file, with this code:

```
Namespace mysite
    Partial Public Class Startup

        Private realm As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:RPIdentifier")
        Private aadInstance As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:AADInstance")
        Private tenant As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:Tenant")
        Private metadata As String = String.Format("{0}/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml", aadInstance)
        Private authority As String = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant)

        Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())

            app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(realm, metadata)
        End Sub  

    End Class
End Namespace
```

But, when I run my code, I get this error:

> The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
>    - No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
>    - The given type or method 'startup.cs' was not found. Try specifying the Assembly. To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting
>   owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
>   To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the
>   appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or
>   configuration method name in your web.config.    Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: The following
>   errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
>    - No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
>    - The given type or method 'startup.cs' was not found. Try specifying the Assembly. To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting
>   owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
>   To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the
>   appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or
>   configuration method name in your web.config.

Can anyone help be in converting this code from MVC c# to Web Form/VB.net?

thanks

Comment: Try to change OwinStartup attribute and include appropriate namespaces `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Namespace1.Namespace2.Startup))]`

Comment: @cloudikka Thank you for responding.  I have added the namespace wrappers around my class and added your suggestion.  I have updated my code, here as well.  But, this does not seem to help as the same error occurs

Comment: What I ended up doing, which seems to work, is change the one file I had in C# to vb.  I thought using both languages would be interoperitable , due to the CLRT, but I guess not.  The issue I had was changing [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(mysite.Startup))] to VB, which I figured out (<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(mysite.Startup))>)